# ¿Como instalo admin LTE en su versión 3 via composer?

Tags: laravel, composer

sucede que instalaba admin LTE via composer así:

```
composer require acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel
```

Pero me instala es la versión 2 de adminLTE, yo quiero adminLTE 3 y no tener que instalarlo de forma manual con assets, archivos, cdn etc

Comment: intenta poniendo la version acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel="3.*" o simplemente acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel=3.*

Comment: adminLTE  3 no existe, por lo que no vas a tener un paquete con el. Lo que si existe es adminLTE  con bootstrap 3, y para eso esta la versión 2 de ese paquete

Comment: adminLTE 3 sí existe tengo entendido, y tiene bootstrap 4, es nuevo, busca en su pagina oficial